# EnvDTE parsing function code [longer]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, envdte

I'm trying to analyze `C#` project source code via VisualStudio's `EnvDTE` COM. The desired task is to:

1. Locate `CodeClass` with given name within the project structure. [done]
2. Find all its public `{get; set;}` properties. [done]
3. Locate its public constructor (the one with the number of parameters matching the count of found properties). [done]
4. Try to match the constructor parameters to the public properties. This step relies on some assumptions:

   - There *should* be a constructor in following form present in the class:

     ```
     public ClassName(typeC paramC, TypeA paramA, typeB paramB...)
     {
         PropA = paramA;
         PropC = paramC;
         PropB = paramB;
         ...
     }
     ```
   - There *should* be only direct parameter-to-property assignments like `PropA = paramA`, nothing like `propA = paramB + paramC` is allowed.

In ideal world, I would like to recognize which parameter is assigned to which property without any additional assumptions or metadata added to the source class like:

- There is any rule for parameter order.
- There is any rule for assignment order.
- There is any rule for parameter/property naming convention.
- There is any rule for additional attributes associated with the properties.

**The question is:** could we analyze the described constructor body via the `EnvDTE`?

I already have `CodeFunction` object representing this identified constructor also as his collection of `CodeParameter` parameters, but I'm not able to reach the code (not sure if it is even possible, but the enumeration member `vsCMElement.vsCMElementAssignmentStmt` gives me hope it could be)...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that the `CodeFunction` (`EnvDTE`) does not support access to the method body :-(other than text-only)-:

[Get all code statements code statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473588/get-all-code-statements-in-specific-code-element-with-envdte)
[Lack of code model support inside methods](http://blogs.msmvps.com/carlosq/2009/01/30/the-lack-of-code-model-support-inside-methods/)